# Ionic Zip extract text file contents always empty

Tags: c#, zip, ionic-framework

Given the code:

```
using (var s = new MemoryStream())
{
    entry.Extract(s);

    if (fileExtension.Equals("json"))
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
        {
            var json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            if (!Functions.ValidJSON(json))
            {
                errorMessage = "'" + entry.FileName + "' contains invalid JSON data: " + json;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Entry.FileName` is `data.json` which exists in the zip, and `entry.UncompressedSize > 0` as it contains JSON data.  However, the `json` var is always empty.

What am I doing wrong?  I am expecting it to contain the text contents of the file.

Comment: I believe you just need to set the Memory Stream's `Position` back to `0` after you `Extract` and before `Read`. It gets incremented as it gets written to, but now you need to read so it needs to be reset.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to set the Memory Stream's `Position` back to `0` after you `Extract` and before `Read`.

`Position` gets incremented as the stream gets written to, but now you need to read so it needs to be reset back to `0`.